# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'AccessControl'

Tags: azure

We have the sitecore azure module installed, and everything seems to be fine.  However, when we attempt to spin up an editing or a delivery farm, we get the following error message:

> 4‎/‎11‎/‎‎2017 ‎6‎:‎07‎:‎49‎ ‎PM111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production
> [P] '[XXX]Sitecore_Core' - Transfer data failed
> System.ApplicationException: 111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production [P]
> '[XXX]Sitecore_Core' - Transfer data failed --->
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name
> 'AccessControl'. at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.DeployDatabasePipelineProcessor.DoDeploy[T](Func3
> func, Int32 repeat, IEnumerable1 objects, Database targetDatabase,
> Action1 exceptionCallBack) at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.DeployDatabasePipelineProcessor.DoDeploy[T](Func3
> func, Int32 numThreads, Int32 repeat, IEnumerable`1 list, Database
> targetDatabase) at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.TransferData.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase
> arguments) at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase
> args)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ‎4‎/‎11‎/‎‎2017 ‎6‎:‎07‎:‎48‎ ‎PM111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production [P] Transfer data
> '[XXX]Sitecore_Core'- [start] ‎4‎/‎11‎/‎‎2017 ‎6‎:‎07‎:‎48‎
> ‎PM111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production [P] Copy indexes
> '[XXX]Sitecore_Core' [done] ‎4‎/‎11‎/‎‎2017 ‎6‎:‎07‎:‎38‎
> ‎PM111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production [P] Copy indexes
> '[XXX]Sitecore_Core'- [start] ‎4‎/‎11‎/‎‎2017 ‎6‎:‎07‎:‎38‎
> ‎PM111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production [P] Deploying tables
> '[XXX]Sitecore_Core' [done]
>
> ‎4‎/‎11‎/‎‎2017 ‎6‎:‎07‎:‎36‎ ‎PM111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production
> [P] '[XXX]Sitecore_Web' - Transfer data failed
> System.ApplicationException: 111DevEusCd02Role01PScAd1Production [P]
> '[XXX]Sitecore_Web' - Transfer data failed --->
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name
> 'AccessControl'. at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.DeployDatabasePipelineProcessor.DoDeploy[T](Func3
> func, Int32 repeat, IEnumerable1 objects, Database targetDatabase,
> Action1 exceptionCallBack) at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.DeployDatabasePipelineProcessor.DoDeploy[T](Func3
> func, Int32 numThreads, Int32 repeat, IEnumerable1 list, Database
> targetDatabase) at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployDatabase.TransferData.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase
> arguments) at
> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase
> args)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Do you have the hotfix installed?  https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure/Sitecore_Azure_81/Sitecore_Azure_81_rev_151119_Hotfix_1076431.aspx  I'm also assuming this is Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 or greater?

Comment: No. It's on Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207 (Update-1)